# Using VSTS.Feed() in Power BI to access odata

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I am trying to use the VSTS.Feed() function in Power BI to read WorkItemSnapshot data.  There are multiple problems.  If I build the entire URL into a single string and call VSTS.Feed () with that, I get the correct information in Power BI desktop, but it will not refresh in Power BI online.  I have been told to use the (undocumented) Query parameter, as shown below, but it is clear that this parameter is ignored.  I can see that the select parameter is ignored on smaller projects, because all columns are returned.  I can see that the filter parameter is ignored because the query fails on larger projects.

Does anyone have a working example of using the Query parameter with VSTS.Feed()?

```
let
    BaseURL = "https://server.analytics.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_odata/WorkItemSnapshot",
    Select = "DateSK,WorkItemId,State,WorkItemType",
    Filter = "WorkItemType eq Bug and State ne Closed and State ne Removed and DateSK ge 20180517 and DateSK le 20180615",
    Source =  VSTS.Feed(BaseURL, [Query=[select=#"Select",filter=#"Filter"]])
in
    Source
```

**Update:**
With the query above, the message I get is shown below.  As I said earlier, it is clearly not using the Filter parameter, and I'm assuming it is not using the Select parameter, either.  I can't query everything because there is too much data, and I can't use a filter because I can't figure out a way to get the Options parameter to work.  With VSTS.AccountContents, the options parameter works well, but those API endpoints don't use $ in parameter names.

> Error: Query result contains 36,788,023 rows and it exceeds maximum allowed size of 300,000. Please reduce the number of records by applying additional filters
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=Visual Studio Team Services
>       ActivityId=881f7988-9863-4e03-8375-0489028f28f3
>       Url=https://server.analytics.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Project/_odata/WorkItemSnapshot
>       error=Record

The query that started this whole line of questioning is simply one with a variable for a start date.

```
 let
    startDate = DateTimeZone.ToText (Date.AddDays(DateTimeZone.UtcNow(), -45), "yyyyMMdd"),
    URL = "https://server.analytics.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_odata/WorkItemSnapshot?$select=DateSK,WorkItemId,State,WorkItemType&$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Bug' and State ne 'Closed' and State ne 'Removed' and DateSK gt " & startDate,
    Source = VSTS.Feed(URL)
 in
    Source
```

While this query mostly works in Power BI desktop (the select clause is ignored), the message I get when the data source is refreshed online is:

> You can't schedule refresh for this dataset because one or more sources currently don't support refresh.
>   Discover Data Sources
>   Query contains unknown or unsupported data sources.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-functions?view=vsts) for VSTS.Feed() contradicts itself, saying both

> The VSTS.Feed function has the same arguments, options and return value format as OData.Feed.

and

> 'VSTS.Feed' provides a subset of the Arguments and Options available through 'OData.Feed'.

To to summarize, I know that I can't combine data sources in Power BI.  Does VSTS.Feed() support the options parameter?  If so, how do I pass a Filter and Select clause to it?

Comment: What's the error message when it cannot refresh?

Comment: Thank you for your interest.  I've updated the original post to show the various queries and their respective error messages.

Answer (score 0):

To get `WorkItemSnapshot` by `vsts.feed`, please refer below query:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://account.analytics.visualstudio.com/project/_odata/v1.0-preview", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    WorkItemSnapshot_table = Source{[Name="WorkItemSnapshot",Signature="table"]}[Data]
in
    WorkItemSnapshot_table
```

**Note:** the URL format should be `https://account.analytics.visualstudio.com/project/_odata/v1.0-preview`, or `https://account.analytics.visualstudio.com/_odata/v1.0-preview`.

And you can refer below documents:

- [Connect to VSTS using the Power BI OData feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/access-analytics-power-bi?view=vsts)
- [Connect using Power Query and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-functions?view=vsts)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but there are many issues with the above code.Primarily, it doesn't address any of the issues of applying the filter or select parameters. Power BI online won't refresh if these parameters are used in the URL because of security scanning/code analysis. Without the filter and select parameters, there is too much data. Further, VSTS.Feed is not the same as OData.Feed (different parameters).